# How to append to result in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I try to return my search result into array to show in blade but get error :

```
$persons = persons::where('name','like',"%$search_term%")->lists('id');

foreach($persons as $person)
{
       $trials = trial::with('samples')->with('persons')->where('persons_id', '=', $person)->get();
}
```

> FatalErrorException in 0bfe77047992e2dce86ae561e266494c line 37: Call
>   to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::appends()

I try to this with + array, but get errors

Comment: Please add more context to your question. Person and Trial and Sample are Eloquent models, right? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I need get list of trials that person_id in persons list

Comment: See my answer. I also suggest that you name your models in singular and CamelCase form. It is more readable that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `whereIn()` method of the query builder. See the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#where-clauses).

```
$persons = Person::where('name', 'like', '%$search_term%')->lists('id');

$trials = Trial::with('samples')->with('persons')->whereIn('person_id', $persons)->get();
```